# JTable not displaying Header

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am creating a GUI using Swing in Java. I created a `GridLayout` and put this table in a cell of the grid layout.

```
String[] columnNames = {"First Name", "Last Name"};
String[][] data = { { "Name1", "Price1" }, { "Name2", "Price2" }, { "Name3", "Price3" }, { "Name4", "Price4" } };
JTable botTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
```

My table is showing the data in the table, but not the table header. How to show the headers in the table?

Answer (score 4):

It's likely you've not wrapped your table in a `JScrollPane` before having the `JScrollPane` added to something that is displayed on the screen.

See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

```
JTable botTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(botTable);

add(scrollPane);
```